# How to dismiss current OSX window controller?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nswindowcontroller

I tried to dismiss current OSX window controller with this but did not work:

```
[self.view.window close];
```

and tried with this and did not work:

```
NSArray *orderedWindows = [NSApp orderedWindows];
NSWindow *frontWindow = orderedWindows[0];
[frontWindow close];
```

and also tried with this and did not work:

```
[self.view.window orderOut:nil];
```

, this one also did not work:

```
[self.view.window orderOut:self];
```

How to dismiss current OSX window controller?

Comment: Is `view` or `window` nil? What do you mean by "did not work"? The window doesn't close, the window controller doesn't get notifications or the window controller isn't released?

Comment: the window is nil. i mean when i click nsbutton to show another window controller, the previous window controller did not close (cannot auto close after show another window controller).

Comment: The 'self' might refer to the new Window Controller, and not the previous one.